# Testing Postgres DB for right permissions programmatically, after populating from .sql file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a project where a postgres db is seeded with a .sql file in the ci test server. This will be build and published as a docker image.

Now, I won't be the only one pushing these .sql files to the server.
So I need to check permissions of all postgres users (and maybe future users) against all databases, introduced by this file.

Example:
User A and B.
User A is a superuser and owns all databases.
User B should only read be able to read in database X.
and so on

**Is there a way to test this programmaticaly**? Other than 'try to read as B from Y -> error?

All other solutions I've found so far are either manually or 'try/error' ones.

Comment: [Access privilege inquiry functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE)

Comment: Thanks.

But:

SELECT has_schema_privilege('B', 'X', 'select'); results in: 
ERROR:  unrecognized privilege type: "select"

Is there a way to ask "has_table_privilege" for select in all tables in the schema 'P' ?
Is there a short way to exclude everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the grants for various types of database object via the [access privilege inquiry functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE). These all work at the level of individual objects, so for any kind of database-wide checks, you will need to combine them with [catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) queries. You'll also need to consult the catalog for any ownership information. [OID types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) are *extremely* helpful when writing these queries.

To check if user `b` has read-only access to all tables in schema `p`:

```
SELECT EVERY(
  has_table_privilege('b', oid, 'SELECT') AND
  NOT has_table_privilege('b', oid, 'INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,TRUNCATE,REFERENCES,TRIGGER')
)
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'r'
  AND relnamespace = 'p'::regnamespace
```

(Note that table privileges are superseded by column-level grants, so you may want to check these too.)

To check if `a` is a superuser:

```
SELECT rolsuper
FROM pg_roles
WHERE rolname = 'a'
```

To check if `a` owns all databases (aside from those created by `initdb`):

```
SELECT EVERY(datdba = 'a'::regrole)
FROM pg_database
WHERE datname NOT IN ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
```